<WARNING>: [zeus/extensions/vk_ext_android_external_memory_android_hardware_buffer/android_hardware_buffer.c:122 GetAndroidHardwareBufferInfo]
I have a page that has a CameraPreview widget in it. When I'm on that page, I get the following warning
W/IMGVK   ( 3316): <WARNING>: [zeus/extensions/vk_ext_android_external_memory_android_hardware_buffer/android_hardware_buffer.c:122 GetAndroidHardwareBufferInfo]
W/IMGVK   ( 3316):    +++++++  
W/IMGVK   ( 3316): psNativeHandle->iFormat:842094169 VkFormat:1000156002

When I'm on the preview page, this warning is constantly being printed over and over, so it immediately floods my debug console. As soon as I take the picture and have been navigated to another page, it stops.
I'm running it on a physical device, an OPPO A15 to be exact.
I looked it up, google didn't give me any results and I still have no idea what it means. It looks like some pretty low-level android stuff, which I don't have any experience with it.
